# In a Canadian TFSA, does interest earned within the account count toward the contribution limit?

Tags: taxes, canada, contribution, canada-revenue-agency, tax-free-savings

I know that there is a limit in the contribution per year in a TSFA. At the moment (2016), if you have never made a contribution then you can contribute around $ 46 500.

BUT, even though all interests, dividends, capital gains, withdrawals, etc. are not **taxable**, does interest count towards TSFA limit? For example, if I contribute $ 30 000 and earn $20 000 in capital gains from mutual funds at the end of the year, will the contribution limit will be considered only on the contribution of $30 000  or in the total of $ 50 000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the principal contribution counts towards the limit.  In your example, if you contribute 30,000 and you earn 20,000, only the 30,000 counts.  To find out exactly how much room you have, you can log into CRA's MyAccount and it will tell you:

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/esrvc-srvce/tx/ndvdls/myccnt/menu-eng.html